# IntelliJ WebStorm Angular animation highlight

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I've a trouble with WebStorm syntax highlight. Now it shows an error and I don't really know why. You can see error text on attached screenshot.

[image: Trouble screenshot]

Angular animation function which one cause this error here:

```
export function SwipeAnimation(axis: 'x' | 'y', time: string) {
  switch (axis) {
    case 'x': {
      return trigger('Swipe', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({
            width: 0
          }),
          animate(`${time} ease-in`)
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          animate(`${time} ease-out`, style({width: 0}))
        ])
      ]);
    }
    case 'y': {
      return trigger('Swipe', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({
            height: 0
          }),
          animate(`${time} ease-in`)
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          animate(`${time} ease-out`, style({height: 0}))
        ])
      ]);
    }
    default: {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Yes, this function works fine. But this error annoys me. Also I've another animation in this project which ones function looks same but there is no error when I use it (as you can see on attached screenshot).

Any ideas for fix this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from [Angular language service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service). The actual error must be `Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'SwipeAnimation' was called`. Not sure why it's displayed this way - must be an issue with Angular/TypeScript/WebStorm integration.
You can get rid of the error by turning the service off in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, **Angular language service**